# Follow a path in Unity

Tags: unity, game-design, movement, path

I want to know how I can make this game object follow the specified path in unity

[image]

Comment: How are you authoring your path? Depending on how that's structured, there may be ways to leverage it directly, minimizing duplication of data and manual setup needed.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Navigation components. You can add a NavMeshAgent to a GameObject and control with a script the path he should walk.

You can easily do in this script:

```
NavMeshAgent navmAgent;
navmAgent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
navmAgent.SetDestination([your destination]);
```

The NavAgent will search for the fastest way to this destination, if you want a more determined path, you could use a set of "RallyPoints".

This is the example from the [Unity tutorial](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/nav-AgentPatrol.html), with a little adjustment:

```
// Patrol.cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class Patrol : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform[] points;
    private int destPoint = 0;
    private NavMeshAgent agent;


    void Start () {
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();

        // Disabling auto-braking allows for continuous movement
        // between points (ie, the agent doesn't slow down as it
        // approaches a destination point).
        agent.autoBraking = false;

        GotoNextPoint();
    }


    void GotoNextPoint() {
        // Returns if no points have been set up
        if (points.Length == 0)
            return;

        // Set the agent to go to the currently selected destination.
        agent.destination = points[destPoint].position;

        //Just choosing the next point (different to tutorial)
        destPoint = Mathf.Max(points.Length-1, ++destPoint);
    }


    void Update () {
        // Choose the next destination point when the agent gets
        // close to the current one.
        if (agent.remainingDistance < 0.5f)
            GotoNextPoint();
    }
}
```

So bascially create a set of points, which determine your path. Give your GameObject a NavMeshAgent and a script which tells the NavMeshAgent to walk aloing your points, similiar to the code above.

If you don't want to use the NavMesh-approach, then you could just interpolate the path and manually update the position of your GameObject.